# Is the set of maximizers of the likelihood singleton for any parameterization of pdfs?

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, maximum-likelihood

Let a realization of a random sample of a normal distribution be $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^N$ such that $x_i$ is a real number. Assume that it is unknown that the distribution is normal and it is desired to identify a probability density function from the realization $\{x_i\}$. Let the approximation of the pdf of the normal distribution be a pdf $f$ that is a mix of a pdf of a normal distribution and a cauchy distribution, such that
$$
f(\theta,x) = \theta_3\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta_2^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\theta_1)^2}{\theta_2^2}\right) + \theta_4\frac{1}{\pi\theta_6\left(1+\left(\frac{x-\theta_5}{\theta_6}\right)^2\right)}
$$
where the parameters $\theta$ are in the set of maximizers to the corresponding likelihood:
$$
\arg \max_{\theta} \prod_{i=1}^N f(\theta, x_i)
$$
subject to
$$
 \theta_1,\theta_3,\theta_4,\theta_5\in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } \theta_2,\theta_6\in \mathbb{R}^{>0}.
$$
and
$$
 \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\theta,x) \, \text{d} x = 1
$$
Since $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^N$ is a realization of a random sample of a normal distribution, it should be that if the mean and standard deviation of the normal distribution is $\mu$ and $\sigma$, then asymptotically, as the number of observations $N$ tends to infinity, a maximizer should be $\theta = (\mu,\sigma,1,0,0,0)$. My question is: is this the only maximizer? In general, if the pdf f is a mix of a normal pdf and many other pdfs will the set of maximizers be a singleton?

Edit, a higher level formulation of my question:

Consider another identification problem. Let a dataset $\{(x_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^N$ be such that $y_i$ is a real number response to the real number input $x_i$. For simplicity let the dataset be such that every $x_i$ is related to a unique $y_i$. Then, the set
$$
\arg \min_f \sum_{i=1}^N \|y_i-f(x_i)\|^2
$$
subject to $f$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$, will contain infinitely many functions, every function which passes through every datapoint.  Returning to an identification problem similar to the one in my original question. Let the dataset be a collection of real numbers $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^N$. Is it that the set
$$
\arg \max_f \prod_{i=1}^N f(x_i)
$$
subject to $f(x)$ is a non-zero real number and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \text{d}x= 1$, contains infinitely many functions $f$? Does a "likelihood" optimization criterion have the same property as the mean-squared-error criterion? That a flexible parameterization of models implies that there are many different models with the same performance according to the "likelihood" criterion? Could this be illustrated?

Comment: Since $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^N$ can take any values, including those more closely suggesting $\theta_4> 0$,  there is no reason to suppose that the maximum likelihood estimate of $\theta_4$ will always be $0$, even if the data was in fact selected when it was.  Incidentally, you may want to add $\theta_3$ and $\theta_4$ must be non-negative and $\theta_3+\theta_4=1$

Comment: @Henry, I realize that I forgot to add that I am wondering about the asymptotic case, when the number of observations $N$ tends to infinity. For a finite number of observations I agree that there is no reason for $\theta_4$ to be zero, or even that $(\mu,\sigma, 1,0,0,0)$ is a maximizer due to the specific realization of the observations. The conditions you propose makes sense, but they are irrelevant for my question since including them only restricts the set of maximizers. I realize that maybe a better formulation of my question is: if, for any $N$, the set of maximizers is a singleton.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identifiability